# jQuery Ajax : call ajax inside ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using this code for a contact form:
http://spyrestudios.com/coding-a-minimalist-contact-form-with-captcha-spam-protection/

I have this menu list:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="company"><a href="#"> company</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="aboutus"><a href="#" >aboutus</a></li>
    <li class="contactus"><a href="#" >contactus</a></li>
  </ul>  
  </li>
  <li class="services"><a href="#">services</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to call the contact form with ajax like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".menu li.contactus", function(e) {

  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#contactform").load("contact.php");

});
```

And here is the contact form code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

 <div id="wrapper">
<div id="contactwrapper">
<form id="contact" name="contact" method="post" action="contact.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="check" value="01">
    <small>*all form fields are required.</small>

    <label for="name" id="namelabel">Name:<span class="err topp">enter your name</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="textinput">


    <label for="email" id="emailabel">E-mail:<span class="err topp">enter a valid e-mail address</span></label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="textinput">


    <label for="message" id="msglabel">Message:<span class="err txarea">share some stuff with us</span></label>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="msgtextarea"></textarea>


    <img src="captcha.php" id="captchaimg">

    <label for="captcha" id="captchalabel">You're not a spammer, right?<span class="err capter">your CAPTCHA code looks wrong</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="captchavalue" id="captchavalue" class="textcaptcha">


    <section id="subber">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" name="submitlink" id="submitlink" class="btn">Send Message</a>
    </section>
</form>
</div>
   </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     function checkValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
     var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);

return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};

var mailsendstatus;
function userSendMailStatus(uname, uemail, umsg, ucaptcha) {
// checking for some valid user name
if(!uname) {
    $("#namelabel").children(".err").fadeIn('slow');
}
else if(uname.length > 3) {
    $("#namelabel").children(".err").fadeOut('slow');       
}

// checking for valid email
if(!checkValidEmailAddress(uemail)) {
    $("#emailabel").children(".err").fadeIn('slow');
}
else if(checkValidEmailAddress(uemail)) {
    $("#emailabel").children(".err").fadeOut('slow');   
}

// checking for valid message
if(!umsg) {
    $("#msglabel").children(".err").fadeIn('slow');
}
else if(umsg.length > 5) {
    $("#msglabel").children(".err").fadeOut('slow');
}

// ajax check for captcha code
$.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'captcha_check.php',
        data: $("#contact").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == "false") {
                mailsendstatus = false;
                $("#captchalabel").children(".err").fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else if(data == "true"){
                $("#captchalabel").children(".err").fadeOut('slow');

                if(uname.length > 3 && umsg.length > 5 && checkValidEmailAddress(uemail)) {
                    // in this case all of our inputs look good
                    // so we say true and send the mail
                    mailsendstatus = true;

                    $("#subber").html('<img src="load.gif" alt="loading...">');

                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'sendmail.php',
                            data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                            success: function(data) {

                                if(data == "yes") {
                                    alert("aaa");
                                $("#contactwrapper").slideUp(650, function(){
                                    $(this).before("<strong>Yep your mail has been sent!</strong>");
                                });
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ); // close sending email ajax call 
                } // close if logic for mailsendstatus true
            } // close check CAPTCHA return true
        } // close ajax success callback function
    } // close ajax bracket open
);

return mailsendstatus;
   }

   $(document).ready(function(){
$("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });

$("#submitlink").bind("click", function(e){
    var usercaptvalue = $("#captchavalue").val();
    var subnamevalue  = $("#name").val();
    var emailvalue    = $("#email").val();
    var msgvalue      = $("#message").val();


    var postchecks = userSendMailStatus(subnamevalue, emailvalue, msgvalue, usercaptvalue);
});
  });
</script>
```

The contact form is checking for captcha and send the data with jquery ajax.
So, the ajax code inside the php page doesn't work.

Is it possible to call ajax inside this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to serve javascript with the form. Serve all the necessary javascript **once** in the original page download, then it is available to be used as many times as is required. In fact, you don't need to re-serve the whole form either; just enough data data to reset the form for another CAPTCHA iteration (typically nothing more than one or two image urls and a unique identifier).

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `load()` jQuery loads Html.

If you need javascript, try using [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to get the specified javascript from a file.

You can also run an `iframe` to avoid this or try embedding your contact form javascript into the `index` page.